# How to propagate from parent command to child command in grails

Tags: grails, spring-validator

I have the following...

```
static constraints = {
  items nullable: true , validator: { val, obj ->
      if(val){
          for(int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++){
              BundleDefinitionCommand bdc = val[i]
              def errors = []
              val.each{
                  if(!bdc.validate()){
                      obj.errors.addAllErrors(bdc.errors.getAllErrors())
                  }
              }
              String test = "test"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But when I run the validator I get...

```
No signature of method: grails.validation.ValidationErrors.addAllErrors() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList) values:....
```

I also tried...

```
obj.errors.addAllErrors(bdc.errors)
```

Comment: `obj.errors.addAllErrors(bdc.errors)` is closer to what you want, not `obj.errors.addAllErrors(bdc.errors.getAllErrors())`, but I don't think either is going to work.  The latter is going to throw a `MissingMethodException` because you are passing the wrong type of object as an argument.  The former is going to be ok as far as that goes, but I think then you are going to get an error because you are adding an Error that belongs to 1 object to another object's errors and I think that is going to result in an IllegalArgumentException with a message to that effect. (continued in next comment)

Comment: The framework should be handling this for you and it can, but it currently does not.  We have some outstanding relevant JIRA issues, including https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11414.  I will take a look at that soon and probably get that resolved.  We are going to release 2.4.2 and 2.3.11 probably very soon and I may or may not get to it by then.  If not, probably the next round. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Any way we could "hack it" with metaClass?

Comment: I don't know why you would need to engage the services of a metalClass. You could just iterate over the child errors and for each of them add a new error to the parent.

Comment: That is what I am struggling with for example what code do I use? Can I even do that I havent been able to save them yet. A simple example would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change your validator signature to

```
validator: { val, obj, errors ->
```

and use that third parameter like so:

```
errors.addAllErrors(bdc.errors.getAllErrors())
```

Also, scratch the temp `errors` array and `String test`.

```
items nullable: true , validator: { val, obj, errors ->
    if(val){
        for(int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++){
            BundleDefinitionCommand bdc = val[i]
            val.each{
                if(!bdc.validate()){
                    errors.addAllErrors(bdc.errors.getAllErrors())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome I will check it out. For now I think we have shelved this until the JIRA is completed. Then I won't have to worry about the custom validator :-)